# rbind for named vectors Named num

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I obtained two named vectors from ColSums doing something like this:

```
MA <- ColSums(DF==1)
MAF<- MA/nrow(DF)

>str(MAF)
Named num [1:501124] 0.435 0.4502 0.5498 0 0.0785 ...
- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:501124] "AX-90649662" "AX-90649663" "AX-91377601" "AX-90649678" ...
```

Now want to merge two vectors that look like this:

```
head(MAF)

AX-90649662 AX-90649663 AX-91377601 AX-90649678 AX-91453449 AX-90649677
0.43504532  0.45015106  0.54984894  0.00000000  0.07854985  0.00000000

head(MAY_counts)

AX-90649662 AX-90649663 AX-91377601 AX-90649678 AX-91453449 AX-90649677
0.5649547   0.5498489   0.4501511   1.0000000   0.9214502   1.0000000
```

if I use a simple `rbind` like this:

```
rbind(MAF, MAY_counts)
```

My output now have 5 rows and 3 of them are filled witg NAs

f I use something like this:

```
 rbind(as.data.frame(MAF),  as.data.frame(MAY_counts))
```

I have the error:

```
 Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
 names do not match previous names
```

However the names of my dataframes are identical:

```
 > identical(names(MAY_counts), names(MAF) )
 [1] TRUE
```

My expected output is the next data frame:

```
  AX-90649662 AX-90649663 AX-91377601 AX-90649678 AX-91453449 AX-90649677
1 0.43504532  0.45015106  0.54984894  0.00000000  0.07854985  0.00000000
2 0.5649547   0.5498489   0.4501511   1.0000000   0.9214502   1.0000000
```

Could someone tell me how I could achieve this?

I added some extra information to answer the questions.

Comment: Are those named vectors? If so, simple `rbind` should work

Comment: `data.frame(rbind(MAF, MAY_counts))`

Comment: what is the error? do you have different class for the two vectors?

Answer (score 1):

I think using `rbind()` is enough. Assuming `A` and `B` are named vectors as below

```
A <- `names<-`(1:5,letters[1:5])
B <- `names<-`(6:10,letters[1:5])
```

then `rbind()` makes:

```
AB <- rbind(A,B)
> AB
  a b c d  e
A 1 2 3 4  5
B 6 7 8 9 10
```

If you further want `AB` as a data frame, then use `data.frame()`

```
AB <- data.frame(AB,row.names = NULL)
```

such that

```
> AB
  a b c d  e
1 1 2 3 4  5
2 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(MAF, MAY_counts)
```